# Using PurgeCss with Laravelmix and PostCss

Tags: github, webpack, postcss, laravel-mix

I was trying to install PurgeCss on my githubpage project. I am using Laravelmix as a standalone dependency and I only have the index.html file on the root folder to be scanned by purgeCSS. I am attaching two images: one of the folder structure and one for the current webpack.mix.js configuration that I'm running.

I would like to know what's the best way and how to use the PurgeCSS in my config. I've tried several times and everytime I run the command: `npm run production` it errors out.

These are the screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmP4x.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCkz9.png

Would appreciate some help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a package named `laravel-mix-purgecss`. The [repository](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-mix-purgecss) is documented and can help you setup purgecss with laravel-mix.

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .purgeCss({ /* My options */ });
```